# Error when making Ajax REST API calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I have this application that I am trying to create.
The application should login (using REST API), and respond with a session id.
I have created a button, which calls the JavaScript function that performs the ajax call, which in turn tries to login.

The results are appended to the div (appscan_results)

Here's is the code

```
<html>
<head>
<title> AppScan Issues Exporter </title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
function login(){
    var request = $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"myurl",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data:{
            "userId": "username",
            "password": "password",
            "featureKey": "AppScanEnterpriseUser",
            "clientVersion": "",
            "clientIp": "",
            "clientHostName": ""
            },
        });

    request.done(function (jqXHR){
        alert('Success');
        $("#appscan_results").html(jqXHR.responseText);
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR) {
        alert('Failure');
        $("#appscan_results").html(jqXHR.responseText);
    });
}
</script>
<button onclick="login()">Get Issues</button>
<div id="appscan_login"></div>
<div id="appscan_results"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

After it runs, I get the following error:

```
Exception thrown by application class 'org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest:195' 

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('u' (code 117)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') at [Source: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTInputStream@d80cceaa; line: 1, column: 2]

at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:195)
at com.ibm.websphere.jaxrs.server.IBMRestServlet.service(IBMRestServlet.java:106)
at [internal classes]
at com.ibm.appscan.server.filters.ClickjackFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:192)
at [internal classes]
```

What am I missing in the code?

PS: I have tested the REST call using REST API client and I do get a response,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException
```

Your servlet/rest controller is not able to parse the Input JSON string  and convert it to a Valid Java Object.

Change data to

```
 data:JSON.stringify({
            userId: "username",
            password: "password",
            featureKey: "AppScanEnterpriseUser",
            clientVersion: "",
            clientIp: "",
            clientHostName: ""
            },
        })
```

Comment: Hi madhairsilence,
Thanks, this did the trick.

After that the Request is successful.